# Error after adding dependencies to build.grade file android

Tags: android, dependencies, retrofit, build.gradle, rx-android

I am attempting to import `retrofit 2.0` to use the `gson` converter, `rx java adapter`, simple `xml` converter. When I added the simple xml converter, I receive these warnings and an error. I'm using the sdk version 23.

How do I fix this error?

Warnings:

> Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3 is ignored for debug as it may
>   be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>
> Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  // rxAndroid
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
  // Retrofit
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta2' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add a **libs** folder into the project and also add the **.jar** file. In Android Studio try to find them, right click on de **.jar** file and **add as a library** (or something). The Android Studio does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your library to libs folder. If libs directory is not present then   add it under app directory.
2. Now right click on your project and select **open module settings**.
   It will launch new window called as project structure.
3. Then select app from left menu and dependencies from top then click on
   **+** from right. It will show one menu and then select module dependency.
4. You will get list of library, select your library from there and click apply.